# Can we detect a highly composite number and determine its number in the list?

Tags: functions, reference-request, divisor-counting-function

For every positive integer $m$ let $f(m)=n$ be the $m$-th highly composite number. A positive integer is called highly-composite if it has more divisors then every smaller positive integer.

Suppose , some positive integer $k$ is given.

> Can we efficiently determine
>
> - whether there is some positive integer $l$ with $f(l)=k$ ? In other words , can we efficiently find out whether $k$ is a highly composite number ?
> - If $k$ is highly composite , can we determine efficiently the positive integer $l$ ? In other words , can we find out the number in the numbered list of highly composite numbers ?

I am aware of necessary conditions for $k$ to be highly composite , but not of sufficient conditions. For the determination of $l$ , I have no idea at all. Has all this been worked out by someone ?

In OEIS , the first $10\ 000$ highly composite numbers are listed , but I am looking for a general method also working for much larger numbers.

Comment: addressed in an article of Nicolas, about work in the dissertation of Robin, his student https://www.genealogy.math.ndsu.nodak.edu/id.php?id=65866  .... http://math.univ-lyon1.fr/homes-www/nicolas/   and   http://math.univ-lyon1.fr/homes-www/nicolas/publications.html   ...   and  number 87  is http://math.univ-lyon1.fr/homes-www/nicolas/hcnrevisited.pdf

Comment: short version:  a highly composite number  cannot be amazingly different from the  consecutive superior highly composite integers   that bound it, one smaller and one bigger. (SHC numbers are fast  once you get the program correct; they are also huge) .  Robin gave details on constructing all  highly composite numbers between  consecutive SHC.

Comment: Meanwhile, in this Nicolas article, he introduces the "benefit" method on book pages 226-228; evidently he introduced this in reference [36].

Comment: this looks good  http://math.univ-lyon1.fr/~nicolas/hcnHR.pdf   see page 25